# How to test React Native "Pressable" onPress function

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

Here is my react native code

```
    <Pressable
      onPress={handleSignIn}>
      <Text style={styles.linkTextStyle}>{signInLinkText}</Text>
    </Pressable>
```

I want to write unit test case with react native testing library to test onPress function. Could some help me on this?

Comment: If you are using jest , check this link: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#fireeventpress-element-reacttestinstance--void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just use the react native testing library docs here https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#fireeventpress-element-reacttestinstance--void. It shows you all the possibilities of react native testing library which is really good.

Comment: This link returns "Page not found"

Comment: Try this https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#fireevent-api